# Can I have OneNote synchronized via Mesh and SkyDrive at the same time?

Tags: windows-live-mesh, onedrive

Generally, for all my files I use **Live Mesh syncing** and am happy with it. One of my synced folders is also "OneNote Notebooks" and it works fine.

However, as I'd like to access my OneNote notebooks from my smartphone as well, it would be easiest to use Microsoft's OneNote **mobile application which syncs with SkyDrive**. My question is, when I share my notebooks over SkyDrive, should I remove the notebook's folder from Live Mesh or can I keep it there so that both SkyDrive sync and Live Mesh will be *both* in place?

(The reason why I would want to keep Mesh is that is is a proven solution for me and would create another "backup" copy on the "synced storage". But I guess that if there is any chance of my files to get screwed it's not such a big deal to leave SkyDrive.)

P.S. I'm looking for an answer from someone who tried it, not for an answer like "it should be safer to sync via one provider only".

Answer (score 0):

I use OneNote, Live Mesh and SkyDrive. I've removed my OneNote notebook files from the LiveMesh sync and use SkyDrive alone for OneNote. I'm happy with that solution and do believe it provides redundancy. I sync to SkyDrive directly from the OneNote Desktop Application and the iOS OneNote App, so my files are actually in three places.